# Airflow can not load DAG

Tags: docker, airflow

I have installed WSL2 and Docker Desktop. Within WSL2, I installed Airflow using Docker Compose.

When accessing localhost:8080, I can see 34 example DAGs displayed. I created a folder C:\Users\ktsha\airflow_dags and within it, I used Chat GPT to create a simple DAG that prints "Hello World", saving this as print_hello.py.

In docker-compose.yml under airflow-server:, I added volumes as follows:

volumes:

- /mnt/c/Users/ktsha/airflow_dags:/opt/airflow/dags

After restarting the Docker container, I accessed the Airflow container and confirmed that print_hello.py exists in /opt/airflow/dags.

However, the issue is that the DAG I created is not displayed in the WebUI. Only the initial 34 examples remain.

I have tried several container restarts and attempted to clear the browser cache, to no avail.

I also checked the dags_folder setting in airflow.cfg, which seemed fine:

cat airflow.cfg | grep dags_folder
dags_folder = /opt/airflow/dags

I additionally checked the permissions for the DAG file and found no issues:

-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 974 Jul 13 05:34 print_hello.py

At this point, I am unsure of what else to check... any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I checked airflow log, but it is weird, logs are not recorded in airflow container but .docker folder located in windows environment.

I though it is weird, so i check docker-compose.yml file located in c:\users\ktsha.docker

Than found this.

compose.yaml

volumes:

```
- ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
- ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
- ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
```

I added only volume under airflow-server:

So, I tried add python file in c:\users\ktsha.docker\dags

Finally my dag loaded on web ui.